# What is the best way to configure multiple kafka topic names using KafkaProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

We have an application which will be communicating with different services over kafka. For example, I need to have 3 consumers (most likely with the same `groupId`) & 3 producers, each reading from and wrting to different topics. I would like to make use of the `KafkaProperties` class to do this.

Listener

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor // lombok
public class MyKafkaListener {

  @NonNull
  private final EventProcessingService eventProcessingService;

  @NonNull
  private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

  @KafkaListener(topics = #{__kafkaProperties.???})
  public void listenMessageA(final ConsumerRecord<String, MessageA> consumerRecord) {
      // Delegate to eventProcessingService
  }

  @KafkaListener(topics = #{__kafkaProperties.???})
  public void listenMessageB(final ConsumerRecord<String, MessageB> consumerRecord) {
      // Delegate to eventProcessingService
  }

  @KafkaListener(topics = #{__kafkaProperties.???})
  public void listenMessageC(final ConsumerRecord<String, MessageC> consumerRecord) {
      // Delegate to eventProcessingService
  }

}
```

Publisher

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor // lombok
public class MyKafkaPublisher<T> {

  @NonNull
  private final KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate;

  @NonNull
  private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

  public void sendMessageX(final MessageX messageX) {
      kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaProperties.???, messageX);
  }

  public void sendMessageY(final MessageY messageY) {
      kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaProperties.???, messageY);
  }

  public void sendMessageZ(final MessageZ messageZ) {
      kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaProperties.???, messageZ);
  }

}
```

A snippet from `application.yml`

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      groupId: myGroupId
      properties:
        someConsumerProp: someValue
        # Should I add my consumer topic names here?
        topicForA: myFavTopicA
        topicForB: myFavTopicB
        topicForC: myFavTopicC
    producer:
      retries: 10
      properties:
        someProducerProp: someValue
        # Should I add my producer topic names here?
        topicForX: myFavTopicX
        topicForY: myFavTopicY
        topicForZ: myFavTopicZ
    properties:
      someCommonProp: someValue
      # Or may be all topic names here?
      listener.topicForA: myFavTopicA
      listener.topicForB: myFavTopicB
      listener.topicForC: myFavTopicC
      publisher.topicForX: myFavTopicX
      publisher.topicForY: myFavTopicY
      publisher.topicForZ: myFavTopicZ
    template:
      # Bonus question: What is the usage of this property?
      default-topic: myDefTopic
```

I want to know what would be the best way to replace the `???` in above classes as suggested by the authors of `spring-kafka` so that I don't have to write any extra `@ConfigurationProperties` class or use `@Value` anywhere but at the same time keep the idea of topic name clear by reading the `application.yml` itself. Or is there any different way provided by the authors to address such scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boot team does not consider AutoConfiguration `Properties` classes as public and can change at any time so beware using them in application code.

Overloading the kafka consumer/producer/admin properties like that is a bit dirty (and Kafka itself might complain about "unknown" properties in its configuration).

It would be better to create your own `@ConfigurationProperties` class.

To specifically answer your question, see `buildProducerProperties()`.